# Гайд-парк или Гайд-Парк?

Tags: прописная

Если название Гайд-парк употребляется не как название королевского парка, а как название исторического региона Лондона и речь идет о домах в этом районе, то писать Гайд-парк надо так же и по-другому? Скажем, Гайд-Парк. Как Блетчли-Парк (англ. Bletchley Park), также известный как Station X — особняк, расположенный в Блетчли (в городе Милтон Кинс) в историческом и церемониальном графстве Бакингемшир в центре Англии.

Answer (score 3):

Топоним не меняет своего написания, за исключением случая, когда Вы пытаетесь проиллюстрировать его эволюцию (тогда, возможно,  надо использовать оригинал написания, manor of Hyde  - Hyde Park). Название парка произошло от названия поместья, приобретенного королем, которое принадлежало фамилии Hyde of Denchworth.

> Иноязычные родовые наименования, входящие в состав географических
>   названий, пишутся с прописной буквы, за исключением тех, которые вошли
>   в русский язык, например: Aму-Дарья, Рио-Негро (хотя дарья и рио
>   значат «река»), но Варангер-фиорд, Де-Лонг-фиорд (слово фиорд
>   существует в русском языке как географический термин).

"Парк" вошел в русский язык и поэтому в составе топонима Гайд-парк пишется с маленькой буквы. Таким образом, правильное написание второго топонима — Блетчли-парк.